# Will it hurt SEO to redirect a friendly alternate domain for marketing?

Tags: url, 301-redirect

A client has a really long hyphenated domain. I can't do anything about this. Although we are looking at new domains too, if that is a better solution.

Need a friendly URL for marketing, for printing on cards and leaflets. 
The target audience is over 50. A friendly URL will make it easier for them to get to the website.

What are the implications for a friendly URL that redirects to the website? 
Can it hurt SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it would hurt SEO is if the new domain had previously been registered and used in an abusive or black hat manner. Just registering a new domain, with no history, and 301 redirecting it will be fine. (But do make sure all the redirects are 301s - permanent - to ensure search engines continue to index the existing domain, and not the new one.)